# Homepage won't scroll beyond certain point

Tags: html, css, wordpress

As its WordPress site so I am sharing ts live link 
[Web-site Link](https://scottallencreative.com/)

This website won't scroll beyond a certain point. Initially, there was a double vertical bar, which I was able to remove...but the page still won't scroll in chrome.

I was initially getting a double vertical scroll bar, but someone else experienced a single vertical scroll bar and single horizontal scroll bar. I have tried all kinds of `overflow:hidden` (and the works) options, but can't seem to resolve.

For additional info, the problem resolves itself if you refresh the page. And it seems to be an issue on smaller monitors (19 in.) vs. 19 in (wide)/21 in.

Please help.

> Site: Wordpress
>
> Theme: Divi

Comment: I think the link is `https://scottallencreative.com/`, you accidentally included the `]` in the link.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO!

1.Remove `overflow-x` and `overflow-y` form the following class

```
.et_pb_section_0 {
    /* overflow-x: scroll; */
    width: 100%;
    /* overflow-y: auto; */
}
```

2.Add `overflow-y: scroll;` on `body`

```
body.custom-background {
   overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

3.Set `overflow-x: hidden;` on `.et_pb_section_0`

```
.et_pb_section_0 {
    overflow-x: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    /* overflow-y: auto; */
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This was helpful.

Comment: Pleasure is all mine, please accept my answer by clicking the left green tick icon on left corner of answer, so that it will help others !